# How to design a html file from a xd file as reference

Tags: html, css, adobe

Is there any way to know parameters like height, width of various parts etc? So that the webpage that I will be making will look just like the xd file

Answer (score 0):

Use `.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the width, height and a location of object.

Answer (score 0):

For `width` and `height`, you can use `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`. According to  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/width), `element.width` and `element.height` are deprecated.

```js
let square = document.getElementById("square")
console.log(square.clientWidth);
console.log(square.clientHeight);
```

```css
#square{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```